# Client Authentication works in Tomcat Windows but not in Tomcat Linux

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I have deployed a WAR in **Tomcat** (TomEE 7.0 plume) with client authentication. It works well on Windows. Then I have installed the same application in Ubuntu Server, with same configuration: TomEE 7 plume, a copy of the same keystore file (JKS), etc. except that I am using OpenJDK 8 in Linux.

When I access the Ubuntu application, the HTTPS works and the page is rendered, but the problem is that even though I have some correct client certificates in my Chrome browser, the client is never authenticated from Ubuntu - as it is from Windows. I have checked some answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276435/why-am-i-getting-an-exception-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538233/javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated-when-load-testi), etc) and activated the debug of the ssh handshake, but the information is not very clear about what is happening. The strange thing is that it works on Windows.

I have tried to create a new JKS from Ubuntu, remove the `ciphers` attribute in `server.xml`, access the application via DNS instead of via IP, force the `clientAuth` with `true`, capture traffic with Wireshark, disable the firewall, etc and nothing solves my issue.

Any idea of what it is happening or how I can continue investigating?

**server.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />


    <GlobalNamingResources>
        <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
    </GlobalNamingResources>

    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   redirectPort="8443" />

        <Connector port="8443"
                        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                        SSLEnabled="true"
                        maxThreads="150"
                        scheme="https"
                        secure="true"
                        clientAuth="want"
                        keystoreFile="...."
                        keystorePass="..."
                        keystoreType="JKS"
                        truststoreFile="..."
                        truststorePass="..."
                        truststoreType="JKS"
                        keyAlias="..."
                        sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
                        ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
                       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
        />

        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase" />
            </Realm>

            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

**catalina.out**

```
Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:0c:02:68:32:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Unsupported extension type_30032, data: 
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {unknown curve 47802, unknown curve 29, secp256r1, secp384r1}
Unsupported extension type_6682, data: 00
***
%% Resuming [Session-3, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1489940010 bytes = { 198, 114, 3, 85, 160, 14, 76, 230, 53, 37, 73, 132, 206, 247, 46, 1, 213, 78, 208, 199, 114, 43, 160, 223, 203, 50, 59, 176 }
Session ID:  {89, 207, 174, 40, 63, 149, 210, 218, 166, 112, 193, 38, 230, 210, 151, 115, 144, 123, 12, 40, 255, 99, 212, 50, 77, 71, 11, 130, 28, 102, 183, 196}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 71 BB D2 14 B7 27 4A E0   8C E5 93 59 DF 77 AB F4  q....'J....Y.w..
0010: 25 AF F3 10 CF 9F 57 85   30 A9 47 48 7C F2 D6 0E  %.....W.0.GH....
Server Nonce:
0000: 59 CF AE 2A C6 72 03 55   A0 0E 4C E6 35 25 49 84  Y..*.r.U..L.5%I.
0010: CE F7 2E 01 D5 4E D0 C7   72 2B A0 DF CB 32 3B B0  .....N..r+...2;.
Master Secret:
0000: 0C 5D 4F B6 F3 6B 86 16   4C 42 7A D2 9A 99 30 60  .]O..k..LBz...0`
0010: D8 A6 A9 F1 AD 6D 36 25   C3 ED F2 2D 81 AC F0 EF  .....m6%...-....
0020: 65 B5 DC EC D8 F4 70 F9   27 FE 82 43 74 E9 80 DB  e.....p.'..Ct...
... no MAC keys used for this cipher
Client write key:
0000: 5B 42 51 E7 E9 CC 16 45   1B 72 74 B1 DD A6 1D 4C  [BQ....E.rt....L
Server write key:
0000: F2 6C EC 51 51 C7 8F 91   DE 4A 8F 9D B1 E2 E8 70  .l.QQ....J.....p
Client write IV:
0000: 9A DE B5 3D                                        ...=
Server write IV:
0000: 46 4E C2 71                                        FN.q
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 81
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 161, 183, 254, 210, 215, 177, 251, 97, 250, 132, 244, 2 }
***
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 110, 171, 171, 236, 64, 1, 31, 53, 61, 163, 76, 102 }
***
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 206
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: -922731054 bytes = { 232, 173, 192, 225, 198, 168, 3, 142, 225, 47, 141, 159, 160, 10, 207, 57, 139, 17, 247, 190, 186, 222, 214, 236, 131, 133, 237, 134 }
Session ID:  {89, 207, 174, 40, 63, 149, 210, 218, 166, 112, 193, 38, 230, 210, 151, 115, 144, 123, 12, 40, 255, 99, 212, 50, 77, 71, 11, 130, 28, 102, 183, 196}
Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0xca:0xca, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, Unknown 0xcc:0xa9, Unknown 0xcc:0xa8, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Unsupported extension type_14906, data: 
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Unsupported extension type_23, data: 
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA256withECDSA, Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0x4), SHA256withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0x5), SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0x6), SHA512withRSA, SHA1withRSA
Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:0c:02:68:32:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Unsupported extension type_30032, data: 
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {unknown curve 2570, unknown curve 29, secp256r1, secp384r1}
Unsupported extension type_56026, data: 00
***
%% Resuming [Session-3, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1489940010 bytes = { 226, 163, 151, 79, 83, 106, 222, 200, 87, 130, 48, 32, 110, 60, 118, 24, 85, 92, 147, 12, 221, 79, 6, 21, 9, 31, 37, 171 }
Session ID:  {89, 207, 174, 40, 63, 149, 210, 218, 166, 112, 193, 38, 230, 210, 151, 115, 144, 123, 12, 40, 255, 99, 212, 50, 77, 71, 11, 130, 28, 102, 183, 196}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: C9 00 3E D2 E8 AD C0 E1   C6 A8 03 8E E1 2F 8D 9F  ..>........../..
0010: A0 0A CF 39 8B 11 F7 BE   BA DE D6 EC 83 85 ED 86 https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 16384
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
verify_data:  { 132, 34, 95, 186, 15, 151, 105, 43, 141, 255, 99, 200 }
***
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 3, 16, 246, 54, 2, 1, 152, 125, 207, 244, 145, 208 }
***
 ...9............
Server Nonce:
0000: 59 CF AE 2A E2 A3 97 4F   53 6A DE C8 57 82 30 20  Y..*...OSj..W.0 
0010: 6E 3C 76 18 55 5C 93 0C   DD 4F 06 15 09 1F 25 AB  n<v.U\...O....%.
Master Secret:
0000: 0C 5D 4F B6 F3 6B 86 16   4C 42 7A D2 9A 99 30 60  .]O..k..LBz...0`
0010: D8 A6 A9 F1 AD 6D 36 25   C3 ED F2 2D 81 AC F0 EF  .....m6%...-....
0020: 65 B5 DC EC D8 F4 70 F9   27 FE 82 43 74 E9 80 DB  e.....p.'..Ct...
... no MAC keys used for this cipher
Client write key:
0000: 45 8C B0 36 8B FA D2 4B   83 BA 90 D8 75 3F E1 B1  E..6...K....u?..
Server write key:
0000: BC 91 84 F4 9B DB 5C EC   F8 05 AE A6 A3 48 BA 7D  ......\......H..
Client write IV:
0000: 9C E7 B8 DA                                        ....
Server write IV:
0000: 5C 36 F2 DE                                        \6..
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 81
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 181, 50, 10, 60, 137, 228, 78, 140, 68, 204, 185, 248 }
***
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 532
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9, READ: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 146, 99, 0, 148, 63, 211, 82, 244, 225, 111, 29, 146 }
***
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 5703
30-Sep-2017 07:46:02.193 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Error trying to obtain a certificate from the client
 javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:431)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESupport.getPeerCertificateChain(JSSESupport.java:97)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.populateSslRequestAttributes(AbstractProcessor.java:597)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:358)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.action(Request.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getAttribute(Request.java:900)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getAttributeNames(Request.java:982)
    at com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener.requestDestroyed(WebappLifecycleListener.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.requestDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.fireRequestDestroyEvent(StandardContext.java:5946)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7, called closeOutbound()
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7, closeOutboundInternal()
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6, called closeOutbound()
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6, closeOutboundInternal()
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
```

**Keystore listing**

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 4 entries

Alias name: .....
Creation date: Sep 20, 2017
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=...
Issuer: CN=..., OU=..., O=...
Serial number: 5d305b71
Valid from: Wed Sep 20 08:26:20 PDT 2017 until: Thu Mar 19 08:26:20 PDT 2037
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  AB:C2:0C:21:C5:5C:F2:D6:69:30:4F:76:7B:AD:74:D4
     SHA1: 2D:B2:83:86:3C:E7:AE:1B:6A:2B:1D:A2:F5:D2:BF:CE:5A:4D:A9:AF
     SHA256: 7F:FF:C2:AD:A6:AC:32:58:14:04:EA:E7:6B:F1:01:C8:3E:64:21:85:D5:54:F6:99:1A:07:AE:4A:9B:A2:26:23
     Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  clientAuth
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  URIName: ...
]



*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: ....
Creation date: Oct 2, 2017
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=...
Issuer: CN=..., OU=..., O=....
Serial number: 28f991cc
Valid from: Mon Oct 02 02:36:37 PDT 2017 until: Tue Mar 31 02:36:37 PDT 2037
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  D0:83:0C:77:64:DE:04:A2:87:3A:99:6D:28:87:83:FD
     SHA1: 63:C7:84:6F:97:97:DA:98:38:38:34:97:16:A8:38:78:28:95:82:C7
     SHA256: FA:A5:36:D1:59:A2:E7:C0:55:6F:57:F9:39:48:4D:9E:AE:5C:39:66:CB:CF:B0:83:4B:1F:72:55:E2:6E:81:16
     Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  clientAuth
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  URIName: .....
]



*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: ...
Creation date: Sep 20, 2017
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=..., OU=..., O=...
Issuer: CN=..., OU=..., O=...
Serial number: 71ed7b34
Valid from: Wed Sep 20 08:26:19 PDT 2017 until: Thu Mar 19 08:26:19 PDT 2037
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  90:DD:A1:A9:E0:16:46:97:43:88:9C:C4:06:FC:46:65
     SHA1: 31:9D:ED:05:EC:53:89:19:E8:46:93:9D:69:E0:49:44:9D:3F:40:7E
     SHA256: D0:78:96:D6:D6:BF:7F:DC:2D:74:7A:B7:AA:A4:E1:17:9A:56:37:68:A4:C9:C5:2F:BE:87:6C:7C:B8:D9:E3:23
     Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:0
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.30 Criticality=true
NameConstraints: [
    Permitted:   GeneralSubtrees:
[
   GeneralSubtree: [
    GeneralName: DNSName: ....
    Minimum: 0      Maximum: 0    ]
]
   ]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: localhost
  DNSName: ....
  IPAddress: 127.0.0.1
]

....
```

---

**EDIT**

After an awful amount of testing, I have copied directly my TomEE Windows version (`apache-tomee-7.0.0-plume`) as *it is* into the Linux server. By doing this, I have to do more tests but it seems to work as expected. So I checked that Linux was using "`apache-tomee-plume-7.0.3`" and I wonder if there might be a bug in that version (?)

Comment: What kind of certificates do you use? Do you create self signed certificates?

Comment: X509. I updated the question. The client certs are signed by the CA cert.